# Select only second record

Tags: oracle

I have a large dataset that I am working with. But to simplify, let say I have a dataset like this:

```
Name  |  Age  |  Hire_Date  |  Manager
---------------------------------------
Bob   |  24   | 01/01/2016  |  Mark
Sue   |  31   | 01/01/2014  |  Fred
Mark  |  37   | 01/01/2011  |  Dawn  <----
Mark  |  37   | 01/01/2011  |  Cindy <----
Jean  |  29   | 01/01/2015  |  Larry
Arron |  47   | 01/01/2004  |  Todd
```

I've put arrows next to the 3rd and 4th rows to show what I need to isolate. Note how Mark's manager changed from Dawn to Cindy. I want to select this dataset but only select one of the two records corresponding to Mark. I'd like to select the second, where the manager is Cindy.

My dataset is quite large and this scenario only happens a few times, where there are two records like the above and the second record only needs to be selected. Is there any way to do this in Oracle to and only select the second of two records in the example situation, and include the rest of the regular records?

Comment: What makes row 3 the "first" record and row 4 the "second" record? There is nothing in the other columns to differentiate them. Is there anything else in your data (which you didn't show)? Or is it a random choice, pick any one of the two? (And no, I can't "note how Mark's manager changed from Dawn to Cindy" - it could just as well have changed from Cindy to Dawn, based on the data you show.)

Comment: @mathguy, the two records are exactly the same except that in the first records the manager name is Dawn, and in the second record the manager name is Cindy. The manager name differentiates them. It's not a random choice. The second record is the most current so I would take it over the first. In other words, Cindy good, Dawn bad. Pretty straight forward.

Comment: Rows in a heap-organized table are inherently unordered.  There is no such thing as a "first" or "second" row without an `ORDER BY` clause.  But there appears to be nothing that can be used to order the results to say that the Cindy row is after the Dawn row.  If that is the case, the question cannot be answered in general.

Comment: "The secnd record is the most current" - but what makes it more current? There is nothing to indicate any order between the two rows. Is there another column you haven't shown that says when the manager changed?

Comment: The OP has asked this question and has left without caring to give more info. I think he is billing on hourly basis working several projects.

Answer (score 0):

assuming there's additional info:

```
select d.Name, d.Age, d.Hire_Date, max(ManagerId)
from mydata d
group by d.Name, d.Age, d.Hire_Date
```

More specifically, you'd probably want to join in a table that has a date field showing when that employee was assigned to that manager, then you simply use the max of the assign date.

Either way, more info is needed.

EDIT:
You definately need additional information.  At a minimum, you need a date field indicating when the manager became the employee's manager.  For Mark's two rows, the manager-effective date field would be later for Cindy than it is for Dawn.

Comment: This answer is essentially removing the Manager name field. That would solve the problem, but I need to keep the manager name field.

Comment: @Zolt - did you miss the part where I said "more info is needed"?  (JK)  but, yes, more info is needed.  Either you need to link in the manager table... you can get the name there, after taking the max of the ID, or you need to consider mathguy's comment, where he asked what makes one row "the second choice".  You could also use a group by clause, then do a sub querry to get the max based on some datetime field, or whatever

Comment: @Zolt - I'd like to know what's going on with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table A , table B
where A.name = B.name  -- add extra conditions to match if you need
and  A.rowid >= B.rowid
```

This above should work; But we need to know why you need it. As well I need to know if something repeats more than twice you need it.

Comment: Where did you get table b from? there is only one table

Comment: Assuming that a row that was inserted later would have a larger `rowid` is a rather problematic assumption.  A later row might have a larger `rowid`, it might have a smaller `rowid`.

Comment: Zolt, both are same table. Try and tell.

Comment: @JustinCave, Read oracle manual. There is nothing like 'later row'.

Comment: Zolt, both are same table. Just keep A & B as it is. change the word 'table' with whatever your table name is . Then comment here if it worked or not. Please read what is correlated query , self join, et c, etc, etc and try . Then ask questions, cross questions, follow up questions etc.

Comment: @JayKumarR - Right, the rows in a heap-organized table are inherently unordered.  So you can't use the `rowid` to determine whether one row is more or less recently inserted than another.  Your query can't be sure whether the Cindy row is from A or B so it doesn't appear to be able to do what the questioner asked.

Comment: @JustinCave, correct in theory. But the Zolt did not say 'those rows that were entered later'. So we do not know which was last , or Zolt really wants last or Zolt wants every duplicate that is not first.

Comment: @Zolt, as expected you ran away, without saying if it worked or not. Brave programmer you are. Learn elementary SQL before riding on others.